# Python 3.x import error SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, builtwith

I'm using macOS Sierra. When importing `builtwith` I get these following error:

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ Daniel$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import builtwith
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/danielotero/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/builtwith/__init__.py", line 43
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I can do to import it correctly?

Comment: Use a version of the module that is compatible with the version of Python you're using.

Comment: `except Exception, e:` is no longer valid syntax in python 3.

Comment: So, that module doesn't support Python 3.  If you put it there yourself, make sure you set it up to use the Python 2 interpreter.  If you installed it with Pip or the like, file a bug report with the library in question.

Comment: @PaulBecotte how can I file a bug report? I install the module with `pip install`

Comment: I'm certain the author is already well aware of the lack of python 3 support. You can look [here](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/builtwith/issues) for the issue tracker. If you want you can raise an issue there, although its likely nothing will happen unless you provide a patch yourself.

Comment: Right, not saying they aren't aware that it doesn't work, saying that  `pip3 install builtwith` should probably not do anything at all instead of installing a broken package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `builtwith` package you installed is developed by Python2, not Python3. So it uses `print` and `Exception` as Python2 does. It also uses urllib2 library which is seperated into two part of urllib library in Python3.
It's better to use Python2 (Python2.7) to finish the work or you have to modify the source code of `builtwith`, that is, change all `print` statement into `print()` function, change `except Exception, e` into `except Exception as e`, and change all `urllib2` functions into functions in `urllib.requests` and `urllib.error`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [module's issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/builtwith/issues/3/error-in-__initpy__), it is not compatible with Python 3. The project owner says

> This module was built with Python 2 in mind. Patches are welcome to also support Python 3, however would need to maintain backwards compatibility.

Since they don't appear to want to port it to Python 3 in order to remain backwards compatible, you should either use Python 2, look for another library, or attempt to port it yourself.