# builtwith: import SyntaxError even after Python 3 support is added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, builtwith

I run `pip install builtwith` and when I imported this module, I faced this issue:

```
>>> import builtwith
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/begueradj/flaskDev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/builtwith/__init__.py", line 43
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which is the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878863/python-3-x-import-error-syntaxerror) where the answers suggest this is not compatible with Python3.

But I am asking again because I read from [here](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/builtwith/src) that support for Python3 is added, so I do not understand why I am facing this issue ... any hints?

Comment: The package at PyPI was last updated in 2015. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/builtwith/1.3.2

Comment: Glad to know someone is using this - have pushed a new version: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/builtwith/1.3.3

Comment: I found your work in a book (about web scrapping), so you are more popular than you may think :)  Good job @hoju

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2017-11-13, the release on PyPI is now Python 3 compatible, and correctly includes the `six` dependency in `setup.py`. Old answer below.

---

The release on PyPI is too old; it dates from 2015:

> **Uploaded on**
>   2015-11-24

This release is not Python 3 compatible.

The [source repository](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/builtwith) indeed has [merged in a pull request updating to support Python 3](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/builtwith/commits/9ae54c84e585dbca9238daaddc959d7557729e78), so you'll have to tell `pip` to install that version:

```
pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/builtwith#egg=builtwith
```

The change added a dependency on the `six` library but did not add this to the `setup.py` metadata; install it manually.

Comment: Thanks for reminder - have pushed a new version to pypi